# Setting Application.Resources through C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I've got this resource in the App.xaml file of my app.

```
//App.xaml
<Application.Resources>
    <sys:String x:Key="ApplicationTitle">FUEL CONSUMPTION</sys:String>
</Application.Resources>
```

And this works phenomenally! But I'm trying to set the resource through the code-behind file, like so:

```
// MainPage.xaml.cs#PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded event
// To get the assembly version number
var nameHelper = 
           new System.Reflection.AssemblyName
              (System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName);
// To change the application title based on the assembly version 
Application.Current.Resources["ApplicationTitle"] = "FUEL CONSUMPTION - v" +
           nameHelper.Version.Major + "." + nameHelper.Version.Minor;
```

But every time I try to assign it, I get a `NotImplentedException` thrown at me. This is to expect since apparently the setter for resources is implemented this way, but is there a way around that?

I want to use the resources to make binding easy down the road.

Comment: Why won`t you put into Resources value "FUEL CONSUMPTION - v{0}.{1}" and then use it with `String.Format(Resources.ApplicationTitle, nameHelper.Version.Major, nameHelper.Version.Minor)`?

Comment: That only gives `"FUEL CONSUMPTION - v{0}.{1}`, sadly

Comment: Where do you use this? XAML? Code? Edit your post and add usage there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try: `App.Current.Resources.Add("Key",Value);`

Comment: If I try to do that, the debugger just gives me a `ArgumentException was unhandled` with the accompanying text `An item with the same key has already been added.`

Comment: Then check for existence of that key, if it doesn't exists add the key else change its value. It works like a normal dictionary. If you cant get it, let me know. I will help you :)

Comment: As I wrote in my question, I only get a `NotImplentedException` when I try to edit the resource.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to the problem. A great thanks to **Milan Aggarwal** for putting me onto the solution.

The solutionis the following code put into the `Application_Launching` event handler.

```
var nameHelper = new System.Reflection.AssemblyName
    (System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName);

if (Application.Current.Resources.Contains("ApplicationTitle")) 
    Application.Current.Resources.Remove("ApplicationTitle");

Application.Current.Resources.Add("ApplicationTitle", 
    "FUEL CONSUMPTION - v" + nameHelper.Version.Major + "." +
    nameHelper.Version.Minor);
```

Turns out that the application title doesn't get updated if the bound object is updated. The change of the resource has to happen before the `PhoneApplicationPage` object is created.